# Why cornering wind tunnel rotate?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, aerodynamics, turbulence

Why cornering [wind tunnel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oD7Jk7mm8o) 
rotate, why is not just curved?

A curved wind tunnel has a radial pressure gradient, but this pressure gradient doesn't exist in a real turn, so how do you get zero pressure gradient in a tunnel section?

In real life P1=P2, but in curved wind tunnel section P2 > P1 , so how get same pressures in curved tunnel?
[image]